# How to have Eclipse CDT output 64bit binaries on Windows?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am using CDT on Windows 7 64 bit. I want to use JNA in Java on compiled Dlls. But how do I tell eclipse to build 64bit binaries (my JVM is 64 bits, so they have to be like that).

Answer (score 2):

CDT itself doesn't build anything.  What compiler are you using?
I would imagine you would need to use a 64 bit compiler.
MinGW-w64 would be what I would use.
http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/

edit: oops didn't see it was asked in 2011